# How do I bulk delete rows in Cassandra using the Java driver using partial primary key?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a table where the primary key is comprised of an account and an id. I need to use both as the "id" isn't unique across all accounts.

In certain edge cases (not a hot path), we often need to delete all rows associated with an account but in Cassandra, you need to specify all the parts of the primary key to delete rows. In order to get around this, I first read all "ids" for an "account" and then delete it. Some accounts maybe have a couple of million rows and the code I've written - while functional - it seems horribly inefficient.

```
public List<MyObject> findAll(String account) {
    final ResultSet result = session.execute(QueryBuilder.select()
            .all()
            .from(TABLE)
            .where(eq("account", account)));

    return mapper.map(result).all();
}

@Override
public void deleteAll(String account) {
    findAll(account).forEachRemaining(object -> delete(account, object.getMyId()));
}
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this? My concerns are the following:

1. The findAll will fetch all the records back to the application server. Is there a way I can do a `DISTINCT` operation to only fetch the "ids".
2. The delete operations aren't batched and therefore might not be performant.

Comment: is your primary key is `(account, id)`, or `((account,id))`?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 answers here, depending on the structure of the primary key:

1. if it's `(account, id)`, then you can delete whole partition using the CQL command `DELETE FROM table WHERE account = ...` - this is most effective way of deleting data, as you generate only one tombstone for whole partition. (Cassandra allow to delete data by primary key, range inside partition, or whole partition).
2. if it's `((account,id))` (composite partition key), then you need to perform full cluster scan to find all combinations of `account` and `id`, and delete corresponding partitions. The effective performing of the full scan is tricky thing if you have a lot of data, but [you can find code example here](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/driver-1.x/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/TokenRangesScan.java).   Another possibility is to perform `SELECT DISTINCT account, id FROM table`, and perform filtering on the client side to get only rows for given `account` value.

Answer (score 0):

I use Datastax cassandra-java-driver 4.14.x.
There you can get a Stream of rows, with that an approach could perhaps be:

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface ProductDao extends BaseDao<Product> {

    @Select
    Stream<Product> findProductStreamByAttachmentId(final UUID attachmentId);
}
```

Service Class:

```
public class DeviceService {

   public void delete(final Product product) {
       this.productMapper.productDao().delete(product);
   }

   public void deleteProductByAttachementId(final UUID attachmentId) {
       this.productMapper
       .productDao()
       .findProductStreamByAttachmentId(attachmentId)
       .forEach(this::delete);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't appear to match with your schema which is explains why Alex Ott wants to find out what your primary key is.

If the table's primary key is `(account ,id)` then your partition key is `account` and have rows of IDs. If this is the case, your code is effectively doing a full table scan which is very expensive and inefficient.

If you post your `DELETE` statement, it will give us a better idea of the table schema. Cheers!

Comment: Why should a select by partition key do a full table scan? In my opinion it will retrieve only the partitions assigned with this key. Moreover it is additonally known from which node the cluster has to retrive the data.